# MenuItemLocator unable to find shell

Tags: java, swt, automated-tests, window-tester

I'm using WindowTester to automate testing of an Eclipse RCP application. When I try to automate menu interaction like this:

```
IUIContext ui = getUI();
ui.click(new MenuItemLocator("Window/Show View/My View"));
```

I get an exception.

```
com.windowtester.runtime.WidgetNotFoundException: No menubar found for active shell
```

The menubar exists, of course. It is created by Eclipse. I contribute to it via an extension point under org.eclipse.ui.commands.

How can I automate interaction with these menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test thread is getting ahead of the UI thread. The menubar doesn't yet exist when the `MenuItemLocator` looks for it. Add a delay to ensure that the application has finished initializing before starting the test.

```
ui.wait(new ShellLocator("Application Title").isVisible());
```